# Set a value for CGRect.frame.size from a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, pointers, casting

I generate a dictionary from a JSON string, and one of the value of the dictionary aims to be used as the height of a WebView object.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [jsonParser objectWithString:response];
CGFloat *height = [dic valueForKey:@"intHeightPixels"];
CGRect frame = webView.frame;
frame.size.height = height;
webView.frame = frame;
```

In line 2 I get the following error:

> Initializing 'CGFloat' (aka float) with an expression of incompatible type 'id'.

I'm newbie in Objective C I don't know if this has something go see with pointers, casting, please give me some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try  `CGFloat *height = [[dic valueForKey:@"intHeightPixels"] floatValue];`
In dictionaries there is only object (here it's a NSNumber)

Comment: you're awesome, i don't exactly know what the end of the line means ¿is casting or something?] thank's a lot!

Comment: cgfloat height       and cgfloat *height == totally different

Answer (score 4):

you can take particular value in string i.e,

```
NSString *str=[arr valueForKey:@"location"];
CGRect rect9 = CGRectFromString(str);
```

This will convert to CGRect so that you can use it in the place of Frame